# Getting NoClassDefFoundError for a class present in the project

Tags: java

```
decodeThread = new DecodeThread(activity, decodeFormats, characterSet,
    new ViewfinderResultPointCallback(activity.getViewfinderView()));
```

For the above code I am getting below exception:

```
01-24 01:33:02.078: E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.main.onlinecart.ViewfinderResultPointCallback
```

The class `ViewfinderResultPointCallback` is present in the same package of the calling class. I am not getting the error for other classes that are being used from the same package. What can be a possible problem here? Anything related to classpath? Where can i crosscheck the class path variable?

I am using eclipse (on mac os x) and running the project from Run configuration.

The class `ViewfinderResultPointCallback` implements another class `ResultPointCallback` which is not in the same package but it is present in a jar added in the build path of the project. And i see one exception in the log:

```
01-24 01:33:01.968: I/dalvikvm(708): Failed resolving com/main/onlinecart/ViewfinderResultPointCallback; interface 472 'Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPointCallback;' 
01-24 01:33:01.968: W/dalvikvm(708): Link of class 'Lcom/main/onlinecart/ViewfinderResultPointCallback;' failed
```

but there are many other classes from the same jar which are not throwing any error.

Comment: You should edit your post to add the information from the comments you added below.

Comment: Edited. BTW error solved as explained below in my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The NoClassDefFoundError was because of my class' dependency on one of the interfaces from a jar. The error got solved when i added the jar to my project's libs directory. This is required because i am working on an android project and when .apk file is created, it adds the jars from libs folder for run time use.

Comment: My class (in the project) doesn't implement any interfaces and only extends a class (also in the project, not in a JAR). Still gives NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is not the actual problem. There should be another exception before that.
You should be looking for an exception which happens during the static initialization of the class in the message (ViewfinderResultPointCallback). Any access to this class will trigger NoClassDefFound but it means only that the class is not loaded.

Comment: The class ViewfinderResultPointCallback implements another class ResultPointCallback which is not in the same package but it is present in a jar added in the build path of the project. And i see one exception in the log:

01-24 01:33:01.968: I/dalvikvm(708): Failed resolving Lcom/main/onlinecart/ViewfinderResultPointCallback; interface 472 'Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPointCallback;'

01-24 01:33:01.968: W/dalvikvm(708): Link of class 'Lcom/main/onlinecart/ViewfinderResultPointCallback;' failed

But there are many other classes from the same jar which are not throwing any error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like com.google.zxing.ResultPointCallback is not in your classpath.

Comment: I added the jar containing ResultPointCallback to build path. I understood from some post that the class path for build and run time are different? Where can i set the class path for run time? I am using mac os and when i see env in terminal i dont see classpath variable there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Error got solved when i added the jar to my libs folder.

Comment: Only error the Junit Failure Trace shows is NoClassDefError.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse `NoClassDefFoundError` with `ClassNotFoundException`. The first might also occur if the class in question implements an interface and either of the two is provided in a new version (they don't match anymore). See http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Error got solved when i added the jar to my libs folder.

Comment: My class doesn't implement an interface. I still get  NoClassDefFoundError .